# unable to solve the routing in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am using jobeet's tutorial and I am following sonataAdmin.
I have configured my app/config/routing.yml as follow:

```
admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin
```

I have also configured my config.yml as follow:

```
# app/config/config.yml
sonata_admin:
    title: Jobeet Admin
 
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
 
        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.action:
        sonata.block.service.rss:
```

When i am running the url `http://localhost/admin/dashboard` then I am getting the problem

> Cannot import resource "C:/wamp/www/Symfony/app/config." from
>   "C:/wamp/www/Symfony/app/config\routing.yml".

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is not a valid resource. The `resource`-directive is used to import external configurations, but `.` points nowhere. See [Including External Routing Resources](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#including-external-routing-resources) for further information. I even guess, that `sonata_admin` is not a type too. It is usually something like `xml`, or `annotation` depending where `resource` points to.

Comment: please, explain, what do I need to write instead of "." ? I didn't get it at all :(

Comment: @SergeVelikanov Did you add the `SonataAdminBundle`-class to your kernel?

Answer (score 0):

This problem may also be caused by typo in service configuration in MyBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml Wich was my case.